# Please explain the usefulness of blocks in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, block

I've recently been trying to understand the importance of blocks in programming (Objective-C in particular). They're obviously used quite a lot in iOS/Cocoa APIs, so I'm trying to understand them.

Mostly, I still don't understand why you would use a block versus just creating a separate helper function. For example, if I create a block that implements some sorting function, wouldn't it be easier to create that function as a method of a helper class so all objects in the code could use it more easily?

Comment: What if your sorting function is a once-off that is not used elsewhere? You would be minimising the surface area of your code and increasing code locality by using a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks are a nice alternative to callbacks or delegates, if for nothing else than improving code readability by keeping your business logic local to the calling code.

But they're so much more: highly useful for asynchronicity, and a necessity if you want to use [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to improve performance.

Other than Apples official docs, I can highly recommend reading the excellent [Practical Blocks](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html) by Mike Ash.

Comment: I think the idea of "keeping the business logic local to the calling code" is where I'm getting tripped up. What if you need to reuse the business logic? Doesn't keeping it close to the code less its reusability?

Comment: Blocks don't stop you refactoring reusable code to public or private helpers, but they can help increase code brevity and re-use in complementary ways. Lets say you refactor some reusable code containing an asynchronous operation to `myNewHelperMethod:(id)obj`. Now suppose you want your calling object to do stuff after the helper completes. You could use delegation or NSNotifications, but both are quite heavyweight for this and muddy the flow of control. Instead, you can have you helper receive a block from the caller: `mynewHelperMethod:(id)obj withCompletionBlock:^(id obj)aBlock`

Answer (score 2):

A nice feature of blocks is that they can be used wherever objects can be used, so you can e.g. store blocks in an array or dictionary. Another interesting thing is that you can pass blocks within an object or between objects as method arguments, e.g.:

```
- (void)processDataWithBlock:(void (^)(void))block
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations
```

The second method is even a `UIView` API. One could argue that function pointers would do here, but that would be more complicated, less flexible and incoherent. Also, blocks can access local variables and instance variables without passing them as arguments.

That's my 2 cents from blocks user point of view, but I'm none of an expert...